# QuickMapServices not showing basemap for my location - QGIS

Tags: qgis, basemap, quickmapservices

I've plotted several locations based in Auckland, New Zealand, using Grid NZGD2000:ESPG:2193. When I load QuickMapServices and set to the same grid, The basemap produced is situated off Omen. [image]

Comment: I doubt the problem comes from QMS. I would rather think your data is misplaced. Check your data source projection. If possible, publish some examples of X/Y values.

Comment: How do you "set to the same grid"? If the basemap is in EPSG:3857, you better leave it in tthat CRS. Do the layers align if you set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857?

Comment: I just change it in properties. When left as default, no basemap shows up.
X/Y shown below: 
5920705 1755253
5918819 1753290
5932578 1753626
5976580 1755875
5912447 1763803

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments, you're doing it wrong.

You can't simply change a layer's CRS if it was defined as another.

How to resolve:
Make sure your layer in the original EPSG:2193 CRS.

If after you load the basemap, the canvas doesn't change to EPSG:3857, change the **canvas** to EPSG:3857, and zoom to your layer's location in New Zealand.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but basemap still not showing even when set at 3857. I'll have a play around with it but can't see what i'm doing wrong at the moment.

Comment: Update: updating to the new version of QGIS solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that updating to the new version of QGIS solved the problem. I assume you updated from a 2.x version to a 3.x version.

The solution to your original problem would have been to turn on "on-the-fly reprojection." This feature allows multiple layers in different CRS to be displayed as if they were all in the same CRS without creating a new version of each layer.

In the QGIS 2.x series, on-the-fly reprojection was an option that could be toggled in the project properties. In QGIS 3.0 and later, on-the-fly reprojection is always on. That's why updating to the new version of QGIS solved your issue.